# TermAggregation with additional TermAggregation not working in AggregationDictionary

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST I have a request looking like this

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<T>()
{
...
    Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("field1")
    {
        Field = "field1",
        Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("field2")
        {
            Field = "field2",
        }
    },
...
}

await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(searchRequest)
```

and I get the results as i expected them, with the Aggregation on "field2" for every alternative off "field1"

I want other aggregations so I put the terms aggregation in an AggregationDictionary.

```
var aggs = new AggregationDictionary();
aggs.Add("field1", new TermsAggregation("field1")
    {
        Field = "field1",
        Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("field2")
        {
            Field = "field2",
        }
    })
...
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<T>()
{
...
    Aggregations = aggs,
...
}
...
await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(searchRequest)
```

Now I get the aggregation on "field1" but no subaggregation on "field2".

Am I missing something or is it supposed to work this way?

Edit 1: Added key to the for AggregationDictionary.Add so that my example code (hopefully) compiles and included my SearchAsync call

Answer (score 0):

```cs
aggs.Add( new TermsAggregation("field1")
    {
        Field = "field1",
        Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("field2")
        {
            Field = "field2",
        }
    })
```

This code won't compile as an [`AggregationDictionary.Add()` method signature](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/9917ff687905711a28e06c18264a7ba1b14a740e/src/Nest/Aggregations/AggregationContainer.cs#L55) is

```cs
public void Add(string key, AggregationContainer value)
```

The following

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var aggs = new AggregationDictionary();
aggs.Add("field1", new TermsAggregation("field1")
{
    Field = "field1",
    Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("field2")
    {
        Field = "field2",
    }
});

var request = new SearchRequest<object>
{
    Aggregations =aggs
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(request);
```

emits the following request

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "field1": {
      "aggs": {
        "field2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "field2"
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at the [documentation on Writing Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#_terse_object_initializer_syntax). Aggregations can be combined together at the same level by `&&`ing them together

Comment: You are of course 100% correct in that I forgot to add the string key in the example, that's not the problem in my actual code thought. I'll try to find the way to edit that in the question

Comment: @TwinC I see the question is edited. I wanted to understand if there is still an issue? Would you also be able to edit to include which version of the client package you're using

Comment: The problem still persists and I has been resorting to a workaround. 
I use version 7.6.0